# Rails: Accessing session in Initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session

I am interested in logging the time taken by my GETs and POSTs(split by time spent in Views, ActiveRecords etc.,).

Following [this blog](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3091-pssst-your-rails-application-has-a-secret-to-tell-you), I created a initializers/timing.rb and subscribed to notifications as below
`ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe /process_action.action_controller/`

I am able to see the timing information of my every GET and POST.

Additionally I have some info in the session(we use redis), that I intend to log along with this timing log, in my initializer

**Questions**

1. How do I access session object in initializers/timing.rb? I did a
   lot of googling around, but could not find an answer that really
   worked.
2. Are the variables I declare and use in timing.rb thread
   safe, in the event of my web server serving multiple http requests
   simultaneously?
3. Is it compulsory that I have to use Modules?

**My softwares**
Rails 3.2.13

**FYI**
Answers in [this link](http://goo.gl/CYeZTE) did not help

Answer (score 0):

The event object that the linked post shows you how to construct contains the controller: `controller = event.payload[:controller]`

Once you've got the controller you can just call `controller.session` to access its session.

Regarding threadsafety, variables local to the block are safe, as are thread local variables. Anything else and you'll have to be careful. Not sure what you mean by having to use modules.

Comment: `payload[:controller]` is just a String :-(